# Angular $http - Make request and return response in one function call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript, angular-promise

I'm trying to create a Model-type class in Angular which approximates Rails model conventions, and has basic database interaction methods on it. The idea is to create essentially an JavaScript ORM that works through the Rails backend via a predictable internal API. Something like this:

```
mod = angular.module('Models')
mod.factory 'User', ($http) ->
  class User

    constructor: (properties) ->
      _.extend(this, properties)

    @find: (id) ->
      $http.get("/api/v1/users/#{id}")
        .success (response) ->
          return User.new(response)
```

That API action which the request hits would then return the serialized user for that ID, which the `success` function would then wrap as an object of that class (`User.new(response)`). That way, I could do this:

```
user = User.find(5)
```

In my CoffeeScript, and the `user` object would be the user in the database with the ID of 5, wrapped as a member of my CoffeeScript class.

The issue is that the way it's coded above, when I call `User.find(5)`, it returns the $http promise object, which can have `.success` etc called on it, **not** the result of calling `$http.get(...)` unwrapping the `success` case, and initializing a `User` object from it. So if I console log `user` after the above, I see something like this:

```
Object {then: function, catch: function, finally: function, success: function, error: function}
```

How could I do this? I'm trying to avoid doing something like this:

```
User.find(5).success (response) ->
  user = User.new(response)
```

Because the above sort of defeats the ease/purpose of the ORM I'm trying to make. (I'm starting with one model, but would eventually like to extract this to a BaseModel). Any ideas? I'm unfamiliar with Angular Promises, (and not much of a pro at JavaScript in general) and have been banging my head against this for a bit.

Thanks,

Sasha

Comment: Most js ORM are based on promises, its the js way...

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? There are lots of solutions including Angular's own [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource).